# How can I save a model from a Sagemaker Pipelines TrainingStep in a specific location i.e. without the unique parent folder?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I know that the [TrainingStep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#step-type-training) saves the model as output by default, but I want to save it in a specific place in my S3 bucket. I need a way to programmatically find where a model is stored, so I want to get rid of the unique parent directory (pipelines-1913hs62gbn9-pipeline-scripts-tra-SAPd32cbD1z/).

I am aware of the output path parameter, but this alters the path after the unique folder name, not the whole one.

I am also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699980/change-model-file-save-location-on-aws-sagemaker-training-job) question which was previously answered, but is not helpful for my case. (Been burned before, so now I am doing a diligent search before asking)

For example
Path where it is saved now:
s3://{my_bucket}/model/pipelines-1913hs62gbn9-pipeline-scripts-tra-SAPd32cbD1z/model.tar.gz

Where I want it:
s3://{my_bucket}/model/model.tar.gz

Any ideas on API calls to make or ways to save it in a specific place?

*edited to fix spelling mistakes

Comment: How did you programmatically access where the outputs were uploaded to s3 after the TrainingStep completes? TrainingStep does not look like it take any outputs param like ProcessingStep does

Comment: @geominded, I have a processing step after the training step in my pipeline. I was able to find the output from the training step saved at opt/ml/model, process it, and output the product as a ProcessingOutput object to a location on my bucket in the processing step definition. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SageMaker training/ pipeline step always adds a unique suffix to the output path provided for the files stored in the model dir. There are 2 ways you can avoid this

1. Rather than storing to /opt/ml/model you can define checkpoint_local_path and checkpoint_s3_uri where the files are copied as is to s3.
2. Write your own s3 uploader which will upload to a known path.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

I have a processing step after the training step in my pipeline. I was able to find the output from the training step saved at opt/ml/model, process it, and output the product as a ProcessingOutput object to a location on my bucket in the processing step definition.